# WiFi not re-connecting after suspend

Tags: networking, wireless, suspend

Issue concerns the WiFi.
When starting the PC, the WiFi adapter is connecting automatically to the configured WiFi network.
But, if closing the lid or going to sleep mode manually, when the PC is waking up, there is no connection to any WiFi network.
When looking for available networks, there is no WiFi function activated; when we try to activate WiFi the following message appears: "no WiFi adapter found".
This is of course contradictory with the fact that it DOES work by (re)starting up the PC.
Solutions already appearing herein give negative results.
Welcome anyone with a straightforward solution, thank you.